# What's the point of Undead Aethernauts?

Tags: dungeons-of-dredmor

I found monsters called **Undead Aethernaut** and Iv'e been wondering what's the point of having them in the game because they don't attack you unless you attack first.

When you mouse over them it says: "Just some dead guy in a suit. It is peaceful and not attacking you at the moment".

Is there anything i should know about them? Is there any point to leaving them alive, is there any penalty for killing them? Basically will killing them or not killing them have any affect at all on the game?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The phrase "It is peaceful and not attacking you at the moment" represents a status that almost any monster in the game can have.  Sometimes monsters spawn with it, and you can also pacify monsters to give them this particular status attribute.

I've definitely come across non-peaceful Undead Aethernauts before, so not all of these guys are peaceful by default.

As far as what you should do, the option is yours.  I tend to kill them *anyway* since all monsters are just shiny loot and XP pinatas waiting to be whacked with whatever big stick I've got at the time.  If you're under attack from a group of monsters, you might leave these guys for last (and avoid using any AoE spells around them) just so that you're not biting off more than you can chew.

Comment: Oh i see. So far all Undead Aethernauts Iv'e seen were peaceful though. And nobody else except them, but I'll trust you on this one, since i haven't came very far in DoD yet.

Comment: @ChrisHateZ, if you take Killer Vegan as a skill tree, all animals spawn with this status.  There's also a few skills/spells that can cause pacification, see Emomancy and Magic Training for examples.